# codeigniter issue in stylesheet attachment

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp, codeigniter-2

**I am learning codeigniter but find tough to attach stylesheet.please help me**

My file structure is

```
www/ci_projects/test_projects/assests/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

I am trying with ***`link_tag()`***
Loading it on view 
But stylesheet is not working

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First go to `application/config/autoload.php`.Then add `$autoload['helper'] = array('html','url');`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>"/>
//OR
<?php echo link_tag('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>


//Image
<?php echo img('asset/images/image1.jpg')?>
//OR
<img src="<?php echo base_url('asset/images/image1.jpg')?>" />

//Javascript
<script src='asset/javascript/yourscript.js'></script>
```

Please Visit [UserGuide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html)

Comment: You Explain well sir :)

Comment: @santosh Thank you . If you find it useful then please upvote the answer :)

Comment: i set this $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:80/'; to solve my problem and it works but now i find problem on submit button when i click submit button it sends me to wamp's index page and the url is coming http://localhost/index.php/enquiry/login :( even it has to send me on login controller and method  <?php echo form_open('login/user_login');?>
 <?php echo form_input(['name'='=>'test','placeholder'=>'type some Thing'] ); ?> 
 <?php echo form_submit('submit','Submit'); ?>
<?php form_close(); ?>

Comment: set config['base_url'] to yours project url i.e. localhost/yourproject/foldername

Answer (score 0):

I Assume Your Base Url

> yoursite.com/ci_projects

```
<link href='<?php echo base_url() ?>test_projects/assests/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```